# Ext.net grid panel not loading from code behind

Tags: c#, ext.net

**Markup**

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" Height="300" Title="Title" EnableViewState="true">

    <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server" />

    <Store>
        <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
    </Store>

</ext:GridPanel>
```

**Codebehind**

```
private void BindData(DataTable dataTable, GridPanel gridPanel, Store store)
{
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader();

    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        //Create the column
        Ext.Net.Column column = new Column();
        column.Header = dataColumn.ColumnName;
        column.DataIndex = dataColumn.ColumnName;

        gridPanel.ColumnModel.Columns.Add(column);

        RecordField recordField = new RecordField();
        recordField.Name = dataColumn.ColumnName;
        jsonReader.IDProperty = dataColumn.ColumnName;
        jsonReader.Fields.Add(recordField);
    }

    store.Reader.Add(jsonReader);

    store.DataSource = dataTable;
    store.DataBind();

    gridPanel.Reconfigure();
}
```

There is no problem in DataTable, but ext.net is not displaying any columns or data.

My concept is that I will pass the sql select query from the text box and the grid panel should be automatically bind with the data we receive from the select query. Is there any mistake in my code or what should I do to display the dynamic data in the GridPanel. I am using ext.net v1.7.

Comment: I can investigate if you provide a standalone runnable test case.

Comment: @DaniilVeriga: Where can I send you the sample project?

Comment: Is an entire project required? I guess a standalone .aspx page would be good enough.

Comment: having same issue , any solution found ?